# How to solve $\sum_{r=0}^{2022} (-1)^r. {2022\choose r}(2022-r)^{2022}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

How to solve $$\sum_{r=0}^{2022} (-1)^r. {2022\choose r}(2022-r)^{2022}$$

My try:

I am able to solve questions like $$\sum_{r=0}^{2022} (-1)^r. {2022\choose r}(2022-r)$$ by expanding it into two summations and solving both separately. But in this question $(2022-r)$ is also raised to power. When I am trying to expand $(2022-r)^{2022}$ using binomial expansion, I am not getting any solvable results.

I even tried replacing $r$ with $2022-r$
$$\sum_{r=0}^{2022} (-1)^{-r}. {2022\choose r}(r)^{2022}$$
But I dont know how to solve this also

Can anyone please provide some hint for alternative approaches or how to proceed with above mentioned approach. Thanks!

Comment: See my recent and elementary answer on the linked question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4711106/1020656

Comment: @An_Elephant thanks! it was the easiest approach

Comment: Glad it helped :)